How to combine asynchronous I/O and CPU-bound tasks efficiently in Python?
I'm working on a Python project where I need to handle both asynchronous I/O tasks (like reading from a file or making API requests) and CPU-bound tasks (like data processing or calculations). I’m struggling to find the best way to combine these two efficiently.
Problem:

I need to make asynchronous API requests and process the results using a CPU-intensive task.
The challenge is that while waiting for I/O (API responses), I want to process the data in parallel to avoid performance bottlenecks.
How do I balance asynchronous I/O and CPU-bound tasks without blocking the event loop or running tasks inefficiently?

For example, in this code:
import asyncio
from time import sleep

async def fetch_data(api_url):
    # Simulate an API request
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return f"Data from {api_url}"

def process_data(data):
    # Simulate CPU-bound data processing
    sleep(3)
    return data.upper()

async def main():
    api_urls = ['api/1', 'api/2', 'api/3']
    
    # Fetch and process data
    tasks = []
    for url in api_urls:
        data = await fetch_data(url)
        result = process_data(data)  # Blocking the event loop here
        tasks.append(result)

    print(tasks)

asyncio.run(main())

This example blocks the event loop when processing the data, making it inefficient. I know I could use concurrent.futures for the CPU-bound part, but I'm not sure how to mix it with asyncio efficiently.

How can I combine async I/O (like await fetch_data()) and CPU-bound tasks (like process_data()) without blocking the event loop?
Is there an efficient way to run CPU-bound tasks in parallel while still handling async I/O without slowing down the whole process?

I expect to:

Make multiple asynchronous API calls.
Process the data without blocking the event loop.
Get the processed results in an efficient and non-blocking way.


In your current code you are invoking fetch_data for each URL and then waiting for it to return a result and then invoking process_data and waiting for its result before you process the next URL. This is serial processing resulting in no concurrency! Of course, process_data as coded will also block the event loop, but your code doesn't have any other tasks running anyway to get blocked.
What you want to do is to create three tasks calling fetch_data concurrently and then when each fetch_data gets its data from the API you want it to then have it submit that data to process_data so that it can run concurrently with the other tasks without blocking the event loop.
You can use asyncio.gather to create your three fetch_data tasks and have them run concurrently. You then want to take the results returned by the API and submit it to process_data, which will be executed in a multiprocessing pool, by calling loop.run_in_executor.
import asyncio
from time import sleep, time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from os import cpu_count

async def fetch_data(api_url, executor):
    print(f'fetch_data {api_url} started at {time()}')
    # Simulate an API request
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    data = f"Data from {api_url}"
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, process_data, data)
    print(f'fetch_data {api_url} returning results at time {time()}')
    return result

def process_data(data):
    # Simulate CPU-bound data processing
    sleep(3)
    return data.upper()

async def main():
    api_urls = ['api/1', 'api/2', 'api/3']
    # Don't create a pool size larger than what we need
    # nor larger than the number of cores we have:
    pool_size = min(len(api_urls), cpu_count())
    # Create the multiprocessing pool:
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(pool_size)

    # Fetch and process data
    results = await asyncio.gather(*(fetch_data(api_url, executor) for api_url in api_urls))
    print(results)

# So this can runder Windows, MacOS, Linux, etc:
if __name__ == '__main__':  # Required for Windows
    asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
fetch_data api/1 started at 1729628872.0385263
fetch_data api/2 started at 1729628872.0385263
fetch_data api/3 started at 1729628872.0396993
fetch_data api/1 returning results at time 1729628877.2545536
fetch_data api/2 returning results at time 1729628877.256133
fetch_data api/3 returning results at time 1729628877.2581544
['DATA FROM API/1', 'DATA FROM API/2', 'DATA FROM API/3']

